# Cannot install z3 package for Haskell on Windows 10

Tags: haskell, z3, haskell-stack

I'm trying to install a project that uses the z3 package under Windows 10 and haskell stack with the following setup:

The [z3 precompiled binaries](https://github.com/Z3Prover/z3/releases) (with includes under ./z3/includes and dll files under ./z3/bin) are located under the project root

```
myProject/
- app/
- dist/
- src/
- z3/
- package.yaml
- Setup.hs
- stack.yaml
- myProject.cabal
```

The `package.yaml` file contains:

```
dependencies:
- base >= 4.7 && < 5
- containers
- parsec
- z3 <= 408.0
```

The `stack.yaml` file contains:

```
extra-deps:
- z3-408.0@sha256:89bbc2d828dc1fe1f19666e8e501c69ce5d0ed8026e4a02f7eae1e69f4a352af

extra-include-dirs:
- ./z3/include
extra-lib-dirs:
- ./z3/lib
```

When I try to stack install I get the following error:

```
Process exited with code: ExitFailure 1
Logs have been written to: C:\Users\jmueller\repos\synthImp\.stack-work\logs\z3-408.0.log

z3-408.0: configure
Progress 1/2

--  While building package z3-408.0 using:
<...>
--extra-include-dirs=C:\Users\jmueller\repos\synthImp\./z3/include 
<...>
--extra-lib-dirs=C:\Users\jmueller\repos\synthImp\./z3/lib

Configuring z3-408.0...
Cabal-simple_Z6RU0evB_2.4.0.1_ghc-8.6.5.exe: Missing dependency on a foreign
library:
* Missing (or bad) C library: z3
This problem can usually be solved by installing the system package that
provides this library (you may need the "-dev" version). If the library is
already installed but in a non-standard location then you can use the flags
--extra-include-dirs= and --extra-lib-dirs= to specify where it is.If the
library file does exist, it may contain errors that are caught by the C
compiler at the preprocessing stage. In this case you can re-run configure
with the verbosity flag -v3 to see the error messages.
```

The extra include and extra lib dirs are there and obviously the include is found too ... there seems to be a problem on the level of the c compiler

I tried both binaries for z3 (x64 and x86) and I don't know how to capture the output of the c preprocessor for further debugging.

Any help is highly appreciated!

Many thanks in advance

Comment: You need to install the missing library, so like `apt-get install libz3-dev` (on Debian systems). I'm not very familiar how to install C libraries on a Windows system.

Comment: On Windows using `stack`, I think @WillemVanOnsem's command would be `stack exec -- pacman -S mingw64/mingw-w64-x86_64-z3`. I'm not sure though; `stack`'s MSYS2 distribution doesn't seem to have a separate `libz3-dev` library.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Isn't that what the `extra-lib-dirs` is supposed to do? The file `libz3.dll` is under `./z3/bin` and `z3.h` is under `./z3/include`. Is it possible to capture the output of the c compiler with stack?

Comment: Have you tried absolute paths in `stack.yaml`.  Or maybe with backslashes?

Comment: @bergey Unfortunately absolute paths don't work either ...

Comment: @jules later questions indicate that you have managed to install z3, could you clarify how you did this?